# Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Address: low-level delegate call failed'

Tags: delegatecall

I have the following function inside my *Registry.sol* contract:

```
function createOrganizerProxy(bytes32 organizationName)
    public
    payable
    returns (address)
  {
    require(!isTaken[organizationName], "This name is already taken");
    address organizerClone = ClonesUpgradeable.clone(OrganizerTemplate);
    ERC1967Proxy organizerProxy = new ERC1967Proxy{ value: msg.value }(
      organizerClone,
      abi.encodeWithSelector(
        Organizer(address(0)).initialize.selector,
        organizationName
      )
    );
    organizerProxyToId[organizerProxy] = organizerCount;
    nameToOrganizer[organizationName] = organizerProxy;
    organizerContractsArray.push(organizerProxy);
    organizerCount++;
    isTaken[organizationName] = true;
    return address(organizerProxy);
  }
```

As it triggers the creation of a proxy, it uses a template (OrganizerTemplate) to clone from. I have already created a script that does this well and stores the address in a *proxyDeployments.ts* file so that I can import it and use it for this test on the hardhat network:

```
import hre from "hardhat";
import { BaseContract, Contract, ContractFactory } from "ethers";
import { ethers, upgrades } from "hardhat";
import { RegistryProxy } from "../proxyDeployments";



let registryProxy: Contract;
let organizerProxy: Contract;

describe("Organizer test", function () {
  it("Should create a new Organizer Proxy", async function () {
    const signers = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    registryProxy = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
      "Registry",
      RegistryProxy,
      signers[0]
    );
    const newProxyAddress = await registryProxy.createOrganizerProxy(
      "0x756e69636f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
        gasLimit: 30000000
      }
    ); 
  });


});
```

And then goes the exception when running `yarn hardhat test network localhost`. Why would the delegate call fail in this case? Any help will be much aapreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the initialization data passed to the ERC1967Proxy contract matches the expected parameters of the organizerClone contract's initialize function. Any mismatch in the initialization data can cause the delegate call to fail. Checking this worked for me

Comment: Provide an example for more pratical guidance for users.